# with recursive query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
WITH t(n) AS (
  SELECT '2009-10-08' from dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT TO_CHAR(to_date(n,'yyyy-mm-dd') + (INTERVAL '1' DAY), 'yyyy-mm-dd' ) FROM t WHERE n > '2009-10-05'
)
SELECT * FROM t;
```

replace '+' with '-' the result of this query does not change at all.

How can this happen?

the query result is

```
2009-10-08
2009-10-07
2009-10-06
2009-10-05
```

Comment: They produce vastly different results when I run the above query and then change the addition of the day interval to subtraction. Are you sure you're running the query with the addition? What version of Oracle are you running this on? I'm on 11.2.0.4.

Comment: @Boneist thanks for verify the result. my install version is 11.2.0.1.0. and just double checked, the result is the same with '+' or '-'

Comment: Then it must be due to bugs in that version of Oracle, as a_horse_with_no_name mentions in their answer. You may need to use the connect by method in order to generate the list of dates correctly, if you can't get your version upgraded to 11.2.0.4 (which, IIRC, has fixes for most (all?) of the dates-and-recursive-subquery-factoring bugs)

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify this is you work with dates directly:

```
WITH t(n) AS (
  SELECT date '2009-10-08' from dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n - 1 
  FROM t 
  WHERE n > date '2009-10-05'
)
SELECT to_char(n, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as n 
FROM t;
```

returns:

```
N         
----------
2009-10-08
2009-10-07
2009-10-06
2009-10-05
```

---

There have been some bugs regarding the use of DATE (or TIMESTAMP) arithmetic in recursive CTEs. The above worked for me using Oracle 12.2.0.1 and 11.2.0.3

Comment: Did you get the issue the OP was reporting with their query in 11.2.0.3? Now that you've mentioned it, I do recall having issues with dates and recursive queries in 11.2.0.3. Thankfully where I work now, we're on 11.2.0.4! (Although I do wonder if I'm doomed to never work on 12c! *{;-) )

Comment: Thanks. this solved my question about date in recursive cte, which I did not ask in SO yet. in oracle 11.2, date arithmetic in recursive not work at all and I have to use to_char.

Comment: @echo: that worked for me in 11.2.0.3

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks. the version I worked on is 11.2.0.1.0.